# smooth all direction player movement using sfml

Tags: sfml

I currently use a switch statement to check if arrrow keys are pressed, set button-specified boolean to true, then I calculate how to move (right and left keys are to change rotation, up/down for movement - calculated with trigonometric functions).
I use statement like this:

```
if(upButtonPressed) 
    this->setPosition(Vector2f(calculate x,calculate y));

//same for down button
if(leftButtonPressed) 
    this->setRotation(deg -= 4.0f);
```

Then it check if button is released and if so sets their boolean to false. This works just fine but when I rotate and try to move forwards/backwards it just stops and I dunno why. How can I make it smooth?

Comment: Please, provide an [mcve] in order for us to help

Comment: What exactly stops? The rotation or the movement? As Dave mentioned, the relevant code would be helpful.